# Problem with Geonode Create Map error 403

Tags: error, proxy, geonode, create

I have installed Geonode 2.4 (developer version) on Ubuntu 14 and all is doing fine. However, the last few days I am getting an error message whenever I try to "create map". The error message is:

> FORBIDEN 403: DEBUG is set to False but the host of the path provided
>   to the proxy service is not in the PROXY_ALLOWED_HOSTS setting.

Can anyone show me how to get this problem fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

First - check /var/log/papche2/error.log to see what the problem is. I found the line :
    Invalid HTTP_HOST header:'53.105.77.32'. 
Second: 
Edit the /etc/geonode/local_settings.py file: 
    Add IP address found above.
    Obtain a Google Maps API key and add it to the file. 
    Set the DEBUG to True

I am not sure which one of these addressed the specific problem, but it now works fine.